# searching dropdown items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my question sounds kind of weird but I need that functionality, here is what my problem is,

I am trying to write a control which acts like a drop down with check box list items in it, after searching I got the same functionality here

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

my requirement is to give a search in that drop down similar to auto complete, when user types a key word it should filter the drop down values, I am new to Jquery any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: check out [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Comment: thank you, can I customize this js, I mean can I add check boxes to it

Comment: I'm sure you could hack it to support that -- append a check box to each element and bind it to the select method in the plugin itself-- but it does support multiple select on its own, which would provide a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

i made some like this... first create a div to insert here a  control, below create a

tag to insert here the suggests...now via ajax you send the text in the input and get the request in the server (PHP in my case) and make the SQL query (MySQL in my case) and return to the client the result :

data here

for each result...this data insert with $('ul').html(data) ajax function....hope its help you, if it's contact me for send you the complete code...

sorry...im new here i can't upload images !!

Comment: For jQuery samples you can try creating a fiddle on jsFiddle.net, great tool for demonstrating scripting functionality.